# Mac resets after waking up

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I have MacBook Pro Retina with Touch Bar; macOS 10.13.1.

Sometimes when I wake up my Mac by pressing TouchID it is turning on monitors then just resets. I have two Apple USB-C to VGA adapters, one USB hub and one USB-C to Ethernet adapter (all USB-C ports are taken).

Now I have error dump:

```
*** MCA Error Report ***
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz, CPUID: 0x806E9)
CATERR detected! No MCA data found.


*** Device Tree ***
{
    "pcie_cfg_base" : "0xe0000000",
    "pci_devices" :
    {
        "0x0" : "MCHC@0",
        "0x10000" : "IGPU@2",
        "0xa0000" : "XHC1@14",
        "0xb0000" : "IMEI@16",
        "0xc8000" : "URT2@19",
        "0xe0000" : "RP01@1C",
        "0xe4000" : "RP05@1C,4",
        "0xe8000" : "RP09@1D",
        "0xeb000" : "RP12@1D,3",
        "0xf0000" : "URT0@1E",
        "0xf1000" : "URT1@1E,1",
        "0xf8000" : "LPCB@1F",
        "0xf3000" : "SPI1@1E,3",
        "0xfa000" : "PMCR@1F,2",
        "0xfb000" : "HDEF@1F,3",
        "0xfc000" : "SBUS@1F,4",
        "0x100000" : "RP01@1C/IOPP/SSD0@0",
        "0x200000" : "RP12@1D,3/IOPP/ARPT@0",
        "0x8200000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0",
        "0x300000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0",
        "0x8300000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",
        "0x8308000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1",
        "0x400000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",
        "0x408000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@1",
        "0x8310000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2",
        "0x8320000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@4",
        "0x410000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2",
        "0x420000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@4",
        "0x8500000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",
        "0x8400000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0",
        "0x600000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",
        "0x500000" : "RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC3@0"
    },
    "device_mmio" :
    {
        "PCI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xcf8", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4010000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0x4000000000", "s" : "0x10000000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011010000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IMEI@16" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011028000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT2@19" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011027000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP01@1C/IOPP/SSD0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82500000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82800000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0x82840000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC2@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82700000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xaab00000", "s" : "0x40000" },
            { "a" : "0xaab40000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP09@1D/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@2/IOPP/XHC3@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xaaa00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP12@1D,3/IOPP/ARPT@0" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82400000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0x82000000", "s" : "0x400000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT0@1E" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011026000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/URT1@1E,1" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011025000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SPI1@1E,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011024000", "s" : "0x1000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PMCR@1F,2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x82624000", "s" : "0x4000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDEF@1F,3" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011020000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0x4011000000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SBUS@1F,4" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x4011029000", "s" : "0x100" }
        ],
        "DMAC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x0", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0x81", "s" : "0x11" },
            { "a" : "0x93", "s" : "0xd" },
            { "a" : "0xc0", "s" : "0x20" }
        ],
        "FWHD" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" }
        ],
        "IPIC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x24", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x28", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x2c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x30", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x34", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x38", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x3c", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xa8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xac", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb0", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb4", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xb8", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xbc", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4d0", "s" : "0x2" }
        ],
        "MATH" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xf0", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "LDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x2e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x4e", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0x61", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x63", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x65", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x67", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x80", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x92", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0xb2", "s" : "0x2" },
            { "a" : "0xffff", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x1800", "s" : "0xff" },
            { "a" : "0x800", "s" : "0x80" }
        ],
        "RTC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x70", "s" : "0x8" }
        ],
        "TIMR" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x40", "s" : "0x4" },
            { "a" : "0x50", "s" : "0x4" }
        ],
        "SMC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x300", "s" : "0x20" },
            { "a" : "0xfef00000", "s" : "0x10000" }
        ],
        "EC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x62", "s" : "0x1" },
            { "a" : "0x66", "s" : "0x1" }
        ],
        "PDRC" :
        [
            { "a" : "0xfed10000", "s" : "0x8000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed18000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed19000", "s" : "0x1000" },
            { "a" : "0xe0000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfd000000", "s" : "0x1800000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed20000", "s" : "0x20000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed90000", "s" : "0x4000" },
            { "a" : "0xfed45000", "s" : "0x4b000" },
            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },
            { "a" : "0xfee00000", "s" : "0x100000" }
        ],
        "MEM2" :
        [
            { "a" : "0x20000000", "s" : "0x200000" },
            { "a" : "0x40000000", "s" : "0x200000" }
        ]
    }
}



EOF
Model: MacBookPro14,2, BootROM MBP142.0167.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 3,1 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.44f1
Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x171), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.2.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.0f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: USB 10/100/1000 LAN, Ethernet, en7
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: USB Laser Mouse
USB Device: USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: Creative HS-720 Headset
USB Device: iBridge
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.3
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.3
```

Comment: I am going to assume you have a MacBook Pro with four USB-C ports (it's helpful if you tells us the exact model you have).  The hub, is it powered or does it need power from the host?  Have you tried disconnecting all of your attached USB-C devices to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Please specify if this happen: [return]• when your battery is nearly exhausted[return]• when you are powered by battery only.

Comment: I'm always using power adapter. I'll check without dangles. BTW I wrote it is Mac with touch bar, only this model has 4 ports:)

Comment: @Preetygeek Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest you clarify what you mean by *resets*? It's not entirely clear. Also, just in case it ends up being relevant, can you confirm whether you're talking about a 13" MBP with 4 USB-C ports or a 15" MBP?

Comment: I had the same problem today.
MPB 2017 13" 4 USB-C thunderbolt connections, battery at ~90%, and nothing connected to it.

Comment: @SamuelE. Any luck debugging or finding cause?

Comment: @Preetygeek No, im looking into it, but no. If I close and open it now, then it doesn't happen.
It happened at night, the computer was closed, nothing other than VSCode and Chrome running in the background.

Comment: @Preetygeek One thing to note is that my computer just came back from repair a week ago. And they replaced half of the computer.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. It's a 13' MBP with retina and 4 USB-C ports that's 3 months old. The issue first appeared during week one of use. Typically happens as follows:
I close the laptop in the evening with 70%+ battery. Come into the office in the morning, open it and nothing happens and I see a black screen instead of it waking, I can press any keys, open and close and nothing happens. Then I press the power button and it starts loading, I get to the login screen and after login I get the error message with a report similar to the above. It's now happened over a dozen times.

Comment: t's now happened over a dozen times. I cannot figure out what exactly is causing it.

Comment: @user276256 Now I have kernel panic reports instead of hardware errors. I'll go to Apple with this.

Comment: This exact same thing happens to me @user276256 - about twice a week. It's more likely to happen for me if I bring my computer home (it'll be fully charged) and let it sit overnight in a bag before plugging it in in the morning. I haven't had it happen that I remember if I plug it into power and open the lid right after work. 15" Core i7, 2.9 GHz, using 4k monitors at work and at home, both with usb-c-to-Displayport cables.